# What's websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint in wso2 apimanager?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deployed pattern4 in okd, with 2cp, 2gm, 2tm. I have exposed 3 routes: cp gw websub. There is a param in deployment.toml : `websub_event_receiver_http_endpoint = "http://localhost:9021" websub_event_receiver_https_endpoint = "https://localhost:8021"`. What's that for ? Do I have to expose to 8021 to be a route?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a WebSub/Webhook API in API Manager as explained in [1]. If you have any websub APIs, then you will need to expose those endpoints to the outside. Otherwise you don't need to.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/streaming-api/create-and-publish-websub-api/#create-and-publish-a-websubwebhook-api